# Compile error on vscode. type specifier is a C++11 extension

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

How can I compile with C++11 compatible mode on vscode?

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print()
{
    int v[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for (auto x : v) {
        cout << x << '\n';
    }

    for (auto x : {10,21,32,43,54,65}) {
        cout << x << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    print();
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-O2", "-g", "test.cpp"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

**Error**

```
test.cpp:8:10: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (auto x : v) {
```

---

Update 1

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? The error is coming directly from gcc.

Comment: I added my gcc version, I'm not sure the version is used for compiling. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I updated it, had a typo. You can check you current version by running `g++ --version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an old version of gcc. You should upgrade!

You can get this to work by changing

```
"args": ["-O2", "-g", "test.cpp"],
```

to

```
"args": ["-std=c++11", "-O2", "-g", "test.cpp"],
```

but, really, consider upgrading.

Reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I will accept your answer after 5 min.

Comment: Hi Aluan, old post of yours but how do you exactly upgrade? I am using Visual Studio Code and it is using clang and I use g++ in the terminal. From both I get the error above. But when I try to upgrade the compiler g++, it says it is up to date. And how can I update clang via Visual Studio Code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with that specific toolchain. I expect you can look up "how to upgrade Clang" but I've never done it.  note that if you're using a different compiler from the IDE versus from the command line you're likely going to run into problems